# No Geographic Roles on my Tableau Desktop

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api, geo, dataformat

I have a CSV document that has a ***Country*** column. Once I upload it to Tableau Desktop 10.4.2 it recognizes the column data type as a String.

According to [this](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_geographicroles.html) Tableau documentation, it says that applicable data type could be converted to geo type just left clicking the column format an the selecting **Geographic Role**, but there's no such Geographic Role when I do that...

Country names are in english and Tableau version is also in english.

The dataset is in the following [link](https://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/getting_started_data_sets.zip), it is the dataset that Tableau use for its learning path. The column **Country** is on ***Global Superstore Orders 2016.xlsx*** on the sheet **Orders**

Comment: Can you post a sample of your csv?

Comment: Sample is ready, Bernardo

Comment: When I connected to it, Tableau already recognized it as a Geographical location. I did notice the csv has a Region like 'Central US'. But the excel, tableau automatically recognized it as a geo. I'm not able to recreate your issue.

Comment: Problem solved, I just selected 'Repair' option on Uninstall settings. Before this I tried to open geo demos that tableau offers everytime you open it.